# How to determine if there exactly two different bits?

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-manipulation, keil

I'm new to assembly language, and trying to check if there are two diff bits.The original binary number is `1111 1111`,and I wanna check if there are exactly two bits are 0 in first four bits like `1010 1111`. And I tried:

```
  mov r1,#4 ;count for first four bits
  mov r2,#0 ;count for diff bit
  ldr r4,=0xAF ;the number that need to check
  mov r4,r4,lsr #4
count  
  ldr r3,=0x1
  and r3,r4
  cmp r3,#1
  bne notDiff
  add r2,#1
notDiff
  mov r4,r4,lsr #1
  subs r1,#1
  bne toEnd
  b count
toEnd
fin b fin
```

Then check the value of `r2`. Is there an easier way to address this issue?Thanks!

Comment: Which processor are you programming for?  Does it have NEON or Helium?

Comment: @old_timer Thank you! But is there a way to know the position of these zeros at the same time?

Comment: @old_timer Yea it's ARM. To represent the position, I want to store the higher-numbered zero into r0, and the lower one into r1

Comment: And how does TST instruction work in this case?

Comment: There is a way to do this without a loop; and there may be an even faster way, but it's only available if you can use NEON or Helium instructions.  Does the processor you program for have these instructions?

Comment: ARM NEON can popcount efficiently (count the number of set bits), so you can simply check if the result is 6 or not.  Like GCC `__builtin_popcount(x) == 6`.  Or also check `== 2` if you also want to find cases where there are two set bits and the rest are unset.

Comment: @PeterCordes And if this is not available (OP doesn't want to tell me unfortunately), you can perform the `x | (x+1)` operation twice to set the least two cleared bits and then check if the result is equal to `-1` and the previous number was not equal to `-1`.  (even better, complement first and do `x & (x-1)` so you can avoid some `cmp` instructions).

Comment: @fuz Sorry, I only saw your comment. It's not available for me to use NEON or Helium. And I'm programming for LPC2138

Comment: @XYWnot Ok.  That's an ARM7TDMI chip.  Are you programming in ARM or in Thumb mode?

Comment: @fuz It's in ARM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea for the following algorithm is to use the operation `a & a - 1` which clears the least significant set bit in a word.  We perform this operation twice.  After the first time, we want a nonzero result (so at least 2 bits had been set originally) and after the second time, we want a zero result (so at most 2 bits had been set originally).  Recall that we have four bits in total, so two clear bits means that two bits have been set.

Code looks like this:

```
        @ assumes input in R4
        @ increments R2 if there exactly two bits are set
count:  and r4, r4, #0xf0       @ clear out all but the four bits we want to check
        sub r0, r4, #1          @ r0 = r4 - 1
        ands r0, r4, r0         @ r0 = r4 & (r4 - 1)
        bxeq lr                 @ if r0 == 0, we had 0 or 1 bit set: ignore
        sub r1, r0, #1          @ r1 = r0 - 1
        tst r1, r0              @ r0 & (r0 - 1)
        addeq r2, r2, #1        @ if the result was zero, we had 2 bits set
                                @ so go ahead and increment r2
        bx lr
```

An alternative option is to use a look up table for the 16 possible combinations.  As memory is usually quite fast on a micro controller, this might be a good idea:

```
count2: adr r0, #lut            @ load look up table address
        ldrb r0, [r0, r4, lsr #4] @ fetch result from look up table
        add r2, r2, r0          @ add result to R2
        bx lr

lut:    .byte 0, 0, 0, 1
        .byte 0, 1, 1, 0
        .byte 0, 1, 1, 0
        .byte 1, 0, 0, 0
```

Now as a further improvement, this look up table can be implemented as a bit vector:

```
count3: ldr r1, =0x16680000     @ load look up table
        mov r0, r4, lsr #4      @ compute look up table index
        movs r0, r1, lsl r0     @ move desired LUT bit into N flag
        addmi r2, r2, #1        @ increment r2 if N bit set
        bx lr
```

Comment: if the bit position of each zero is needed that can be encoded in the two halves of the byte in the look up table.